# Schengen zone, Article 2(19), i got it from estonia embassy

Tags: canada, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

One or more member state(s) consider you to be a threat to public policy, internal security, public health as defined in Article 2(19) of Regulation (EC) No 562/2006 (Schengen Borders Code) or the international relations of one or more of the member states).

can you give solutions,for this case now what i can do, make appeal or i can make it reapply, why they given this type of reason its mean what reason.

Comment: There would seem to be one whopper of a story that you seem to have failed to include.   Look up the techology  "garbage in, garbage out", an answer can only be as good as the facts you give. Keep this in mind when talking to your lawyer also.

Comment: According to the Schengen Handbook s7.7 https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf#page58 the possibilities are that a) they got a biometric hit indicating a serious problem in your Immigration history or criminal record or b) they’ve identified a risk of disease constituting a public health risk as defined by the International Health Regulations (IHR) of the World Health Organisation (WHO) and other infectious diseases or contagious parasitic diseases